# C# Handling Else Condition Within Nested Ifs

Tags: c#, if-statement

I need to execute an `else` statement from a `if`, and another `if` inside it.

```
if (!BoxA_IsNull && !BoxB_IsNull && !BoxC_IsNull && !BoxD_IsNull) //Scenario 1
{
    if (BoxA == BoxB && BoxC == BoxD) //Scenario 2
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
else
{
    // Do something else if 
    // 1) Scenario 1 hits but not scenario 2
    // 2) Scenario 1 does not hit
}
```

May I know how can I go to `else` statement regardless if `scenario 1` or `scenario 2` hits?

Edit: Apologies on scenario confusion. Have edited as above in else statement

---

At the end I went with the following solution of

```
if ((!BoxA_IsNull && !BoxB_IsNull && !BoxC_IsNull && !BoxD_IsNull) && (BoxA == BoxB && BoxC == BoxD))
{
    //do something
}
```

Reason is because during `if`, it will hit 2nd comparison check if 1st null check fails. The purpose of my 1st null check is to prevent null exception during 2nd comparison check.

Comment: With these `if`s, if scenario 2 happens so does scenario 1, so the `else` seems to be in the right place. Could you give a concrete example of why this isn't working as you expected?

Comment: Apologies on the scenario confusion. I have corrected my else condition on S1 and S2 hit/no hit.

Comment: _The purpose of my 1st null check is to prevent null exception during 2nd comparison check._ This would have been relevant to include in the original question post, IMO :)

Comment: Understood, this is a big time missed out on my part XD @AstridE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the conditions in boolean variables. Then you can reuse them.

```
bool nullCondition = !BoxA_IsNull && !BoxB_IsNull && !BoxC_IsNull && !BoxD_IsNull;
bool equalityCondition = BoxA == BoxB && BoxC == BoxD;

if (nullCondition && equalityCondition) 
{
  // Both conditions are true
}
else 
{
  // Any of equalitycondition or nullcondition is false
}
```

Comment: Yes, although the comment is inaccurate - _"// equalitycondition is false or both are false"_. Either, or both `nullCondition` or `equalityCondition` could be false to hit the `else` branch.

Comment: I actually followed your initial solution of `if ((!BoxA_IsNull && !BoxB_IsNull && !BoxC_IsNull && !BoxD_IsNull) && (BoxA == BoxB && BoxC == BoxD))`, as it will not go to the 2nd comparison check if the 1st null check fails. The purpose of my 1st null check is to prevent null exception during the 2nd comparison check.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the scenarios in two boolean variables, which makes the check more easily:

```
bool scenario1 = !BoxA_IsNull && !BoxB_IsNull && !BoxC_IsNull && !BoxD_IsNull;
bool scenario2 = BoxA == BoxB && BoxC == BoxD
if (scenario1)
{
    if (scenario2)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
if((scenario1 && !scenario2) || !scenario1)
{
    //do something else if either Scenario 1 or 2 hits.
}
```

Depending on what you are doing exactly, you could also give the variables more expressive names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding you question correctly; the logic you seem to want with your example is pretty simple:

```
if (!BoxA_IsNull && !BoxB_IsNull && !BoxC_IsNull && !BoxD_IsNull) 
{
    if (BoxA == BoxB && BoxC == BoxD)
    {
        //Scenario 1 & 2
    }
    else
    {
        //Scenario 1 hits but not scenario 2
    }
}
else
{
     //Scenario 1 does not hit
}
```